# Hibernate Search: Filters with popular terms

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I want to make filter checkboxes like Amazon in order to refine search results. For example, if my entities are Book objects, I want to have some checkboxes with the most common authors and titles from the results.

Using Hibernate Search, is there a straightforward way to get the most common terms according to some fields of my entity class and then filter by them in further user requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably some of your use cases can be solved with the faceting API - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-faceting. Did you have a look at it?